# Animated appearance of new items in a column and disappearance of the first item

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, tailwind-css

I want to achieve exactly the same animation as shown in the video : https://www.loom.com/share/ed8b6af1e97b407aa7715cac6eb6dd3c?sid=645a1f04-c556-41be-b4ac-229afbf8bda7

but I don't know what to use for this , at the moment I have a list of tweets and code to display them .I would like to hear ideas how to implement this or a possible example , it looks very trivial .

My code :

```
    import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react';

const TwitterFeed = () => {
  const tweets = [
    {
      id: 1,
      username: 'example_user1',
      name: 'John Doe',
      tweetText: 'This is a sample tweet. #SampleTweet',
      avatarUrl: 'https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      username: 'example_user2',
      name: 'Jane Smith',
      tweetText: 'Another tweet for the Twitter feed. #NextJS #TailwindCSS',
      avatarUrl: 'https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      username: 'example_user3',
      name: 'Alice Johnson',
      tweetText: 'Yet another tweet for the feed. #WebDevelopment',
      avatarUrl: 'https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3">
      {tweets.map(tweet => (
        <div key={tweet.id} className="bg-additionalBlack rounded-[20px] p-4 relative">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <Image
              src={tweet.avatarUrl}
              width={10}
              height={10}
              alt={`${tweet.username}'s avatar`}
              className="mr-2 h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
            />
            <div className="flex flex-col">
              <span className="font-semibold">{tweet.name}</span>
              <span className="ml-1 text-gray-500">@{tweet.username}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="absolute right-5 top-5">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="22"
                height="18"
                viewBox="0 0 22 18"
                fill="none"
              >
                <path
                  d="M21.4239 2.44385C20.6539 2.79385 19.8239 3.02385 18.9639 3.13385C19.8439 2.60385 20.5239 1.76385 20.8439 0.753848C20.0139 1.25385 19.0939 1.60385 18.1239 1.80385C17.3339 0.943848 16.2239 0.443848 14.9639 0.443848C12.6139 0.443848 10.6939 2.36385 10.6939 4.73385C10.6939 5.07385 10.7339 5.40385 10.8039 5.71385C7.2439 5.53385 4.0739 3.82385 1.9639 1.23385C1.5939 1.86385 1.3839 2.60385 1.3839 3.38385C1.3839 4.87385 2.1339 6.19385 3.2939 6.94385C2.5839 6.94385 1.9239 6.74385 1.34391 6.44385C1.34391 6.44385 1.34391 6.44385 1.34391 6.47385C1.34391 8.55388 2.8239 10.2939 4.7839 10.6839C4.4239 10.7839 4.0439 10.8339 3.6539 10.8339C3.3839 10.8339 3.1139 10.8039 2.8539 10.7539C3.3939 12.4439 4.9639 13.7039 6.8539 13.7339C5.3939 14.8939 3.5439 15.5739 1.5239 15.5739C1.1839 15.5739 0.843896 15.5539 0.503906 15.5139C2.4039 16.7339 4.6639 17.4439 7.0839 17.4439C14.9639 17.4439 19.2939 10.9039 19.2939 5.23385C19.2939 5.04385 19.2939 4.86385 19.2839 4.67385C20.1239 4.07385 20.8439 3.31385 21.4239 2.44385Z"
                  fill="#1DA1F2"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className="mt-2">{tweet.tweetText}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TwitterFeed;
```